# Android Studio java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found
in the classpath:

```
 transforms-3/dc04df3215040707b8fd8b864f3fd379/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.10.jar (version 1.5)
 /transforms-3/3f04d00625adc215dd0f9966626c579f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.31.jar (version 1.5)
/transforms-3/a832180744c3733d7610f75a06c52a46/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
/transforms-3/fba3ed9dc2dca5a06945cd07fe9f552c/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
```

I am not able to run the build because of the above error. My project doesn't have Jdk8. I tried different versions of Kotlin but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `dexOptions` from `build.gradle` file. Let me know if it works.

Comment: i don't have them.